# Create a ranked linked list from existing single linked list

Tags: c, data-structures

I would like to know is there a simple way where I create a ranked linked list based on sorting each number in ascending order on each node from a singular linked list using C. Most of the ranking method I seen is using array. Is it possible to use this [methods](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rank-elements-array/) on linked list.

The program should behave as following:

```
input: singular linked list = -11->9->0->1->null

\\ select the smallest number and rank 1, in this case -11
\\ second smallest number is 0, rank 2,
\\ third smallest number is 1, rank 3
\\ forth smallest number is 9, rank 4

output: ranked linked list   = 1->4->2->3->null
```

Comment: What is a ranked linked list? How do you know what the output should be?

Comment: My suggestion is that you don't look for already existing solutions, finished code, but instead look for *algorithms* that you can then implement in any suitable way. That will teach you a lot more than being part of a [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: I already updated the questions.

Comment: Please explain the shown desired output as a logical consequence of the input. "The first number in desired output is 1 because ...., the second output is 4 because ....".

Comment: Sort the nodes in ASC order & give them ranks?

Comment: yes. Question updated.

Comment: The input list, sorted ascending, would be -11 0 1 9. How does that produce the desired output 1 4 2 3 ?

Comment: Probably should be 1 4 3 2.

Comment: The first rule of thumb about linked lists: don't use them. They are mostly good for failing CS exams. (There are other legitimate uses but they are rare). If this is a school assignment, please say so. It is not forbidden to ask questions about school assignments, there's no need to hide this.

Comment: Not a school assignments, I just want to learn this so that i can use radix sort. I want to convert negative number to ranking.

Comment: Let me update the question to input my code

Comment: 1. Add rank field to the list-nodes 2. prepare an array of node-pointers 3. sort the array in asc/dsc order 4. assign ranks using a desired method.

Comment: What is rank field? The reason why i wanted to do ranking because i want to use it to replace negative number and sort it using redix sort. My redix sort unable to sort negative number.

Comment: And they call it [XY - Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)! Find the smallest (-ve number) in the list. Add (-1 * smallest) to all elements, then radix sort. Subtract smallest from all the elements after sorting. Check for integer overflow, you may need bigger `int` type.

Comment: I see. Let me try it

Comment: but using ranking , should be able to solve too. As i read reference from this reference [https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/push-swap-tutorial-fa746e6aba1e]